# Is it possible to fetch the issue/PR templates of a Github repository, via REST API?

Tags: github, templates, github-api, github-issues

I wanted to pre-fill some Github issue/PR creation forms, by fetching the templates from the repository via REST API.

Is this possible? I've searched in the documentation, but I couldn't find an API for this purpose.